# How to setup a disposable/sticky mailbox relay server?

Tags: email-server, email-bounces

I'm a big fan of Gmail's addressing features (aka '`+`' in address like `my.name+throwaway@gmail.com` => `my.name@gmail.com`).

Unfortunately a lot of services are too dumb to validate an email addresses correctly ( like `/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+@.+/` ) or are aware of this feature and forbid usage of a disposable mail address.

Since I have my own domain, I'd like to setup the smallest possible MX server (without queuing if possible) that would allow routing of my own disposable mailboxes ("created" on the fly) to my gmail account (& thus benefit from Gmail other cool features).

Eg : `throwaway@my.throwaway.subdomaine.my.domain.tld` is to be relayed to `my.name@gmail.com` (disposable mailbox)

or, more practical `yahoo.is.spamming.you@subdomaine.my.domain.tld` (sticky mailbox)

Do you have any ideas ?

Extra :

1. Id like to force usage of substring in the mail adress to prevent
   bruteforcing ... something like `throwaway1-abc@domain`,
   `throwaway2-abc@domain`, ...

   1.1 (*Extra Bonus super prize*) use a flexible routing pattern map :

   - `*-abc@domainA` => `my.name@gmail.com`
   - `*@abc.domainB` => `other.name@yahoo.com`
   - ...
2. Server security & MX security must be ensured :

   2.1 simple & clear solution (eg. small perl / node.js script) or well established software base (Eg. postfix)

   2.2 not an open relay ...
3. Being a computer enthusiast I'm giving a close look to theses related technologies in parallel : DNSSEC, DANE, SPF, DKIM. So it would be cool to be able / to still be able to plug them in ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply set up postfix with `recipient-delimiter = -`; as you noticed, many web-based services don't allow the use of + as a delimiter.

Postfix can route on the delimited address, on the localpart address, or any combination thereof.

No further configuration is necessary to use, say me-ebay@example.com, me-yahoo@example.net, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @adaptr ! Unfortunatly postfix is a monster for me (I use it often but never configured one) and, until now, I didn't found a good tutorial on how to configure it in what I would call "relay mode". From the parameter's doc I think I should go on and play with http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html ... and learn email routing within postfix